# Intuition behind EMF independence of temperature for unit molarity solutions

Tags: electrochemistry

[The Nernst equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nernst_equation) is given as:
$$E= E^o - \frac{RT}{nF} \ln Q$$
Now, it turns out that if all the liquid components in the cell are unit molar i.e: of molarity one, then $Q=1$ and hence $\ln Q=0$ making the EMF temperature independent.

This puzzled me, is there an intuition on why a mixture of unit molarity solution has no dependence on temperature for their EMF?

---

This question could be equivalently asked in terms of Gibb's Free energy, why does Gibb's Free energy become temperature independent if each constituent has molarity of  one:

$$ \Delta G = \Delta G^o + RT \ln Q$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128782/discussion-on-question-by-buraian-intuition-behind-emf-independence-of-temperatu).